# Django foreignkey not getting any user

Tags: python, django, model

I am building a Django app. I have customized the User model. My models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from phonenumber_field.phonenumber import PhoneNumber

# Create your models here.

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone_number,username,email=None, password=None):
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError("You must specify your phone number")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must specify your username")
        
        try:
            user = self.model(phone_number= PhoneNumber.from_string(phone_number=phone_number,region="BD").as_national,
                                                                    username=username,
                                                                    email=self.normalize_email(email))
        except :
            user = self.model(phone_number= PhoneNumber.from_string(phone_number=phone_number,region="BD").as_national,
                                                                    username=username)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_stuffuser(self, phone_number,username,email,password):
        user = self.create_user(phone_number,username,email=email,password=password)
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number,username,email,password):
        user = self.create_user(phone_number,username,email=email,password=password)
        user.staff = True
        user.admin= True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(unique=False,max_length=50)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    email = models.EmailField(unique=False)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username
    
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
    
    def get_email(self):
        return self.email
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.phone_number)
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    objects = UserManager()
```

I am logged in but it is throwing error.
My Ticket model:

```py
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
class Ticket(models.Model):
    from_station = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    to_station = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    purchased_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    travel_on = models.DateTimeField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Customer:{self.customer.username},From:{self.from_station},To:{self.to_station},Travel on:{self.travel_on},Purchased on:{self.purchased_on}"
```

My views.py:

```
@csrf_protect
@login_required
def buyticket(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = Ticket(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('main-home-page')
    else:
        form = Ticket()

    return render(response,'main/ticket.html',{'form':form})
```

The error I got:

```
Ticket has no customer.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ticket/
Django Version:     3.2.4
Exception Type:     RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

Ticket has no customer.

Exception Location:     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py, line 197, in __get__
Python Executable:  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version:     3.9.2
```

A user can have multiple tickets. But it is not taking any user. Whenever I am trying to go to ticket route it calls me to login. I do but then it throws this error.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: error:Ticket has no customer.

Comment: this time i got redirected to login and could login but git error 'ticket has no customer'

Comment: Do you have a form for Ticket? 
If not, your Ticket class should be: class Ticket(forms.Form): - and not models

Comment: I did class Ticket(forms.Form): but I got this:TypeError: 'DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass' object is not iterable

Comment: should i create another .py file amd create Ticket there as class Ticket(forms.Form): ; but I want ticket in admin page too

Comment: should i do Ticket.objects.create()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error shows to you cause You declare the from equal to model
in :

```
 else:
        form = Ticket()
```

You should create another file called forms.py in the app
and do something like that

```
from .models import Ticket
from django.forms import ModelForm

class TicketForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model = Ticket
          fields = '__all__
```

and in views

```
from .forms import TicketForm

def buyticket(response):
    form = TicketForm()
    if response.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('main-home-page')
    else:
        form = TicketForm()

    return render(response,'main/ticket.html',{'form':form})
```

You can get more info in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)